# Binary search tree algorithm crashing when passing a parameter that isn't in the tree to the search function

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

i tried building a binary search tree, everything worked fine when i gave it parameters that were in in the tree, but i wanted to see if it would print 0 when it couldn't find the int in the tree instead when i call search it's crashing.

i tried adding a condition after the first if statement but that ruined the recursion
here's the code:

```
   struct node
{
  int data;
  node* left;
  node* right;
  
  node(int d)
  {
    data = d; 
    left = right = NULL;

  }

};

node* insert(node *root, int n)
{
  if(root == NULL)
  {
    return new node(n);
  }
  else
  {
    node* y;

    if(n <= root->data)
    {
      y = insert(root->left, n);
      root->left = y;
    }
    else
    {
      y = insert(root->right, n);
      root->right = y;
    }

    return root;
  }

}

node* search(node *root,int n)
{
  if(root == NULL || root->data == n)
  {
    return root;
  }
  
  if(root->data < n)
  {
    return search(root->right, n);
  }
  return search(root->left, n);
}

int treemax(node *root)
{
   while(root->right != NULL)
   {
     root = root->right;
   }
   return root->data;
}

int treemin(node *root)
{
  while(root->left != NULL)
  {
    root = root->left;
  }
  return root->data;
}

int main()
{
   node *R = NULL;
   R = insert(R, 33);
   insert(R,12);
   insert(R, 40);
   insert(R, 36);
   insert(R, 21);
  
  
  cout << search(R, 65)->data << endl;
  
  
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
cout << search(R, 65)->data << endl;
```

`search(R, 65)` returns `NULL`. You can't dereference `NULL` by doing `->data` on it. You probably want:

```
Node* result = search(R, 65);
if (result)
{
    cout << result->data << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Not found" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to access null pointer. Pointer returned from search(R,65) is null because аt last step your `root->right` is `null`.
If you want to return 0 if no elements is found you can replace your last line with this:

```
node *result = search(R, 65);
if (result)
 cout << result->data << endl;
else 
 cout << "0" << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a working example. I have added some comments that show what things you can change in the above program to make it safe or better.

```
#include<iostream>
struct node
{
//always initialize built-in type data members  
int data = 0;//initialize any built in type otherwise it will have garbage value
  node* left = nullptr;//initialize any built type as stated above
  node* right = nullptr;//initialize any built in type as stated above
  
  node(int d)
  {
    data = d; 
    left = right = nullptr;

  }

};

node* insert(node *root, int n)
{
  if(root == nullptr)
  {
    return new node(n);
  }
  else
  {
    node* y;

    if(n <= root->data)
    {
      y = insert(root->left, n);
      root->left = y;
    }
    else
    {
      y = insert(root->right, n);
      root->right = y;
    }

    return root;
  }

}

node* search(node *root,int n)
{
  if(root == nullptr || root->data == n)
  {
    return root;
  }
  
  if(root->data < n)
  {
    return search(root->right, n);
  }
  return search(root->left, n);
}

int treemax(node *root)
{
   while(root->right != nullptr)
   {
     root = root->right;
   }
   return root->data;
}

int treemin(node *root)
{
  while(root->left != nullptr)
  {
    root = root->left;
  }
  return root->data;
}

int main()
{
   node *R = nullptr;
   R = insert(R, 33);
   insert(R,12);
   insert(R, 40);
   insert(R, 36);
   insert(R, 21);
  
  
  //std::cout << search(R, 65)->data << std::endl;
    node *value = search(R, 65);
    
    //check if the pointer is valid
    if(value)
    {
        std::cout<< value->data <<std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"cannot access nullptr"<<std::endl;
    }
    
  
  
}
```

The error was because `search(R, 65);` was returning `NULL` and you were trying to access a NULL pointer's data member value.